# Radio buttons for boolean field, how to do a "false"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently trying to insert some simple true/false radio buttons in Rails 3, but I can't find a way to make a radio button insert "false".

My code is the following:

```
<%= f.radio_button :accident_free, true %><label for="auction_accident_free_true">ja</label>
<%= f.radio_button :accident_free, false %><label for="auction_accident_free_false">nein</label>
```

I already tried:

- 1 / 0
- "1" / "0"
- true / false
- "true" / "false"
- "yes" / "no"

but nothing seems to work right for the value false. My field is set with

```
validates_presence_of :accident_free
```

and I always get the message that it has to be filled to continue, when clicking the false button. When clicking the true button, it works fine, but false doesn't get recognized.

Does anyone know how to do it correctly?

Thanks in advance

Arne

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is it:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_presence_of

> `validates_presence_of()` validates that the specified attributes are not blank (as defined by `Object#blank?`)
>
> If you want to validate the presence of a boolean field (where the real values are true and false), you will want to use `validates_inclusion_of :field_name, :in => [true, false]`
>
> This is due to the way `Object#blank?` handles boolean values: `false.blank? # => true`

I tried your example using a scaffold and `"1"` and `"0"` as in

```
<%= f.radio_button :foo, "0" %>
<%= f.radio_button :foo, "1" %>
```

and they worked.

Comment: Hey, thanks so much, that really works :) I'm always fascinated how quick people at stackoverflow are with answering such questions. Got it working now thanks to you!

Comment: One more comment: it works with "true"/"false" even better, as the radio_buttons get correctly preselected when validation fails.

Comment: Excelent, thanks. Additionally I included a clearer message for my radio button field validation: # validates_inclusion_of :field_name, in: [true, false], message: 'choose an option'

Answer (score 3):

I recently came to another solution for this:

```
validates_presence_of :accident_free, :if => 'accident_free.nil?'
```

Explanation [here](http://www.arubystory.com/2015/02/mind-the-gap-part-1.html)

Comment: The above works well. Just make sure your column / field doesn't have a default value defined.