# Rails 3: validation, presence: true is only validating text field but not radio button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, nested-forms

So I'm working on this part of a rails app with nested forms.  I am having trouble with getting validation to work.  So the parent form is a model to store Questions and the child form is a model to store Answers.

There are 3 different types of questions: number (text field), yes/no (radio buttons), agree/disagree (radio buttons).

I have a simple validation in the answers model: `validates :value, presence: true`

So for example I create a question of type number, it generates a text field and if I submit it as empty the validation works and the errors are rendered on the page.  However, if I pick one of the the other 2 options, which are both radio buttons, I can submit the form without making a selection and the validation doesn't work. I noticed in the console that only the question is inserted into the database, but the answer is not (with the radio button form); normally I would assume that at least there would be nil values passed, but the INSERT query doesn't even show up.

I cheated a little by having a hidden field in the radio button forms, and creating a change handler that sets the value of the radio button to the hidden field whenever the radio button selected is changed.  However, I would really like to dig deeper and figure out the real issue, because it's always good to have a back-up in case javascript is disabled.

**Answer Model**

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :value, :user_id, :meter_id, :question_id
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :question

  validates :value, presence: true, :numericality => true

  before_save :associate_with_meter_id
  before_save :associate_with_user_id

  def associate_with_meter_id
    self.meter_id = question.user.meter_id
  end

  def associate_with_user_id
    self.user_id = question.user.id
  end

end
```

**Question Model**

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :description, :taxonomy, :user_id, :answers_attributes
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers

  validates :description, presence: { :on => :create }
  validates :taxonomy, presence: { :on => :create }

  def relevance_score
    rand
  end

end
```

**Log**

```
Started POST "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-12 09:21:25 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"knwvfB6q6Q7qoTprc/3R4Et3r13xWzpAB1Iq8FsRndQ=", "question"=>{"description"=>"How are you?", "taxonomy"=>"yesno"}, "submit_button"=>"Ask"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 585460615 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (4.3ms)  INSERT INTO `questions` (`avganswer`, `coeff`, `created_at`, `description`, `pval`, `quality`, `rank`, `responses`, `rsquare`, `skips`, `taxonomy`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["avganswer", nil], ["coeff", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 12 Jun 2012 13:21:25 UTC +00:00], ["description", "How are you?"], ["pval", 0.0], ["quality", 0.0], ["rank", nil], ["responses", nil], ["rsquare", 0.0], ["skips", nil], ["taxonomy", "yesno"], ["updated_at", Tue, 12 Jun 2012 13:21:25 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 585460615]]
   (0.3ms)  COMMIT
  SQL (0.0ms)  BEGIN
   (0.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/questions
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/questions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-12 09:21:25 -0400
Processing by QuestionsController#index as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 585460615 LIMIT 1
  Question Load (1.3ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`user_id` = 585460615
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered questions/_form.html.erb (23.9ms)
   (0.5ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions` 
  Rendered questions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (48.8ms)
  Question Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` 
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`user_id` = 585460615
  Rendered /Users/gregorygrillone/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bundler/gems/gauges-58ad28a906b2/app/views/gauges/_gauge.html.erb (0.1ms)
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT `questions`.* FROM `questions` 
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `questions` WHERE `questions`.`user_id` = 585460615
Completed 200 OK in 72ms (Views: 62.2ms | ActiveRecord: 4.2ms)


Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-12 09:21:25 -0400
Served asset /application.css - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-06-12 09:21:25] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true


Started GET "/assets/application.js" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-06-12 09:21:25 -0400
Served asset /application.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)
[2012-06-12 09:21:25] WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true
```

**Question controller**

```
class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html, :json

  def index
    @question = current_user.questions.new
    @questions = current_user.questions.all
  end

  def create
    @question = current_user.questions.new(params[:question])
    if !params[:update_button]
      if @question.valid?
        if params[:next_button] || !@question.save
          @questions = current_user.questions.all
          render 'index'
        elsif !params[:next_button] && params[:submit_button] && @question.save
          flash[:success] = "Your question and answer have been saved."
          respond_with @question, :location => questions_path
        end
      else
        @questions = current_user.questions.all
        render 'index'
      end
    else
      @questions = current_user.questions.all
      render 'index'
    end
  end

  def next
    @question = current_user.unanswered.first
    @answer = Answer.new(:question => @question, :user => current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Please post the relevant view code. Additionally, you should post the sections of your models both for questions and answer that reference eachother. The validations and the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` as well.

Comment: Also post the params hash passed in both cases, which you can get from the log file or the server window.

Comment: Have you seen this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112858/radio-buttons-for-boolean-field-how-to-do-a-false

Comment: Ya I did see that when I was doing research earlier. I tried it but it didn't work (except with the text field), the radio buttons just don't seem to be even picking up any validation

Comment: I just discovered that if you have validation and it fails then no INSERT query is generated (which exactly what's happening), but it is still rendering the success page, so maybe it's something in my questions controller (the parent form). I'll post it above, I know it looks a bit ugly so maybe that's causing the issue

Comment: I encountered this same issue.
I understand the problem to be in the browser not submitting the hash for radio inputs in the params instead of submitting an 'empty value' like the other input types.
I've fallen back to a default selection too, but I support the intention to dig deeper into this.
If it's an html fault, I wonder if Rails could work around it with a hidden empty input or alike?

Answer (score 0):

I think your view code is not creating the form structure properly.

You should be able to confirm your controller code is correct, by writing a functional/controller test that posts the params in the format you expect. (much better/faster feedback than trying to post half your app up to StackOverflow!)

You will be able to create a decent test in less than an hour, and that knowledge will make everything else you do that much better and faster. Trust me, it will be worth the effort of learning how to properly test your code.

Once you prove that you have the controller working properly, you'll most likely find that your view code is not creating the form inputs of the nested answer properly. You can see from the log file that it didn't even attempt to post them.

You might want to separate the create and update actions, the code that checks for different buttons is a bit confusing and makes it hard to understand the 'contract' between the page and the controller. (eg. if next but not update but submit...) That's not causing your problem now, but just something you might want to clean up before it bites you later.

Comment: it's strange though, I know that it doesn't even try to post the Answer, but that only happens when no value is given (only for radio buttons). If you select an option the value is properly inserted.

Comment: oh, that's because browsers won't post in that case. Its common with radio buttons to create a default answer, with the idea that they have to choose one or the other.

Comment: well, what value would it post? if the radio buttons are male/female, and they don't select one, what would you want to see? You might be able to fake it out. search for radio button post issues, and maybe you'll find a work around. Or just force a default

Comment: Right now there are 2 different sets of radio buttons: yes/no and agree/disagree (likert scale). So I would like 1 of the values chosen.  I have done a good amount of research and I've tried using a helper method called: validates_inclusion_of. It let's you set values that are valid for input, i.e. 1 (or yes). I tried that, no luck. It's strange the validation only skips if nothing is selected; I tried creating a custom validation method that would fail if a radio button was selected (and it worked), but when I tried to make it fail if there was no value it just skipped the validation

Comment: And ya I was thinking of just setting a default checked radio button, but was trying to find an alternative because I feel that it's bad usability, because if the user accidently submits the form without making the correct selection they may get frustrated

Comment: This is just really strange, so just for kicks in my custom validator I basically said "if value is nil --> add error, else --> add error", so either way there should be an error. And if I do not select a radio button it still submits the form (which doesn't make sense because it should have hit 1 of the if/else statements), but it did work when I selected one of the radio buttons.

Comment: I think the reason its not hitting your validation is because its not creating an answer model. You should see this same behavior in your test. If there is a params set up like {:question => {:id => 1, :answer => {:text => 'blah'}}} that nested answer will populate an answer model and the validations will fire. If the :answer =>{} isn't there, then there isn't a model, hence no validations.