# schema.rb and mysql database issue in ruby on rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, simple-form, schema.rb

First of all, I've been learning Rails for 8 months but feel like I started yesterday, so please bear with me. I'm trying to resolve why my value, called visible, isn't functioning correctly. I'm using Simple_form. 'visible' is the radio button value:

```
 <div class='review-form'>
      <%= simple_form_for(@review) do |f| %>
  # input boxes for current_user to put text here

  #'public' radio button, checked by default, class is for css
  <%= f.radio_button :visible, "true" , :class => "share_button" %>

  #'private' radio button, class is for css
  <%= f.radio_button :visible, "false", :class => "keep_private_button" %>

  #user can cancel
  <%= link_to I18n.t('write_review.cancel_button'), landing_page, 
  :class => 'btn' %>

  #user can submit
  <%= f.button :submit, I18n.t('write_review.submit_button'), 
  :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
```

The idea is that the current_user writes a review - if they make it 'public', any other user can see it, if private, only they can see it. The radio buttons work ok - when I log out, look at the app on different machines etc, the radio button is in the last saved state. The problem is that the current review, @review, is always visible to everybody, regardless of the state of the radio button.

I put `<%= @review.visible? %>` on the review form. Every time I refresh the page it is 'true', even though the radio button might be false. I save the review and @review.visible then matches accordingly. But then I refresh and it goes back to true.

I think the problem could be:

In my schema.rb I have:

```
t.boolean  "visible",                                    :default => true
```

I deleted `:default => true`and there was no improvement but I hear you're not supposed to manually interfere with the schema.rb anyway.

Do you think that default => true is causing the problem? Would doing a 'migration' be the way to go? How would I word that 'default => true' part in the migration?

Finally, while my schema.rb has 'boolean' my actual database has `visible: tinyint(1)` , which I thought was fishy, but I've read online they're in fact the same thing, so I don't think that's the problem - if you think differently, let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't touch db/schema.rb.  That is automatically updated via the migrations and/or the state of your database.  You have the right idea in that you need to remove the default value for 'visible', but you need to do it in a migration.  change_column_default is probably what you want.

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column_default

Also, the boolean vs tinyint(1) is okay.  It's a MySQL thing as MySQL doesn't have true boolean types.

Comment: Cheers, thanks for putting me on the right track. Looking into it now.  The only alternative though is to have default => false, as booleans have to be one or the other, right?

Answer (score 1):

To echo what Phillip said if you need to change your database, you shouldn't do it via schema.rb, you need a migration. You should have a default for booleans on mysql (because otherwise it's a tri-state instead of a binary (true, false, null).

If you think the problem is the default is wrong, you can do a change_column migration, you can generate a migration from the command line tools:

```
rails g migration UpdateTableName
```

Open the migration file (in models/db/migrate/timestamp_update_table_name.rb) and change the code to be:

```
def change 
    update_column :table_name, :columnname, :boolean, :default => false
end
```

then run this via command line tools:

```
rake db:migrate
```

If you think your problem is the form, you could always look at something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112858/radio-buttons-for-boolean-field-how-to-do-a-false) to see if it's the values for your form that are the problem.

Comment: Looking through your ideas now and getting the syntax right before doing the migration - don't want to mess everything up! Changing to 'default => false' - would this not give me the same problem, except always giving me 'false when I refresh, instead of true? You mention tri-state. In the migration file I have in fact 'null' and 'true': add_column :reviews, :visible, :boolean, :null => true, :default => true.....Does this look right?

Comment: Re: this -> Changing to 'default => false' - would this not give me the same problem, except always giving me 'false when I refresh, instead of true? By default, yes, but if you want people to be able to save that field (visible) they are going to control whether it's visible or not, so that just makes it not visible by default.

Comment: Re: your syntax, you don't need both :null => true and :default => true, if you have a default you won't end up with a null. If you want to not allow nulls, you would specify :null => false. Maybe I'm missing why you would want a tri-state? You want the user to either not set it (null), set it as visible or not visible?

Comment: 'By default, yes, but if you want people to be able to save that field (visible) they are going to control whether it's visible or not, so that just makes it not visible by default.' Well, that's the problem! They select the true or false radio button, the true or false state is always saved accordingly, but when I do <% @reviews.visible? %> I always get 'true' (even though radio button is selected to false. I suppose I'll just have to try different migrations and see what works. Thanks for your help!

Comment: sounds like the default value isn't your problem then, it's probably your view code not saving the right value. I'm not using simple form anywhere, so I'm not familiar with it's syntax, but looking at it on github, you could do something like this:  <%= f.input :visble, as: :radio_buttons %>

Comment: Cheers, I'll look into that too.