# Rails application radio buttons do not update boolean field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, radio-button, form-submit

I have a basic Rails form (using rails-bootstrap-forms gem to format) and I would like the radio button to set the boolean field of the object to be made. Here is the code snippet (shortened for brevity):

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@comment) do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name, label: "Name (required)", label_class: "whiteClass" %>
  <%= f.text_field :email, label_class: "whiteClass" %>
  <%= f.form_group :public  do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :public, true, label: "Public", label_class: "whiteClass", inline: true, checked: true %>
    <%= f.radio_button :public, false, label: "Private (Only Paul will see)", label_class: "whiteClass", inline: true %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>

<% end %>
```

I've tried to get the radio buttons to respond from vanilla rails forms but was not successful. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is `public` included in your strong params? And if so, do neither of them work, or are you having an issue where you can't change from true to false?

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue using Jake's answer. Thank you everyone for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a value to your radio buttons:

```
<%= f.radio_button :public, true, label: "Public", label_class: "whiteClass", value: true, inline: true, checked: true %>
<%= f.radio_button :public, false, label: "Private (Only Paul will see)", label_class: "whiteClass", value: false, inline: true %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4112858/radio-buttons-for-boolean-field-how-to-do-a-false)

I think you just need to add

```
validates_inclusion_of :public, :in => [true, false]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `"true"` and `"false"` instead of `true` and `false`:

```
<%= f.form_group :public  do %>
  <%= f.radio_button :public, "true", label: "Public", label_class: "whiteClass", inline: true, checked: true %>
  <%= f.radio_button :public, "false", label: "Private (Only Paul will see)", label_class: "whiteClass", inline: true %>
<% end %>
```

Hope that helps!